# nginx: trouble creating subdomain.subdomain.domain.com

Tags: nginx, domain, subdomain

I'm trying to prototype a website on my server using a default domain name I get through my hosting provider and I'd like to run it off a subdomain but I'm having trouble doing so.

The domain I'm trying to add a subdomain to is:

`ks12345.kimsufi.com`

And I'd like to temporarily run a site off `test.ks12345.kimsufi.com`

the domain does work with my server as visiting `ks12345.kimsufi.com` returns an nginx hello world type message which is what I expect and I have managed to serve pages from `ks12345.kimsufi.com/test` but this messes with all my paths that the site uses so its not really an option.

I've tried a few different things but I cant seem to find a way to access the site from `test.ks12345.kimsufi.com` which is my ultimate goal, does anybody know if this is possible or how to do this?

Here's the contents of the vhost file I'm trying so far:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name test.ks12345.kimsufi.com;

        location / {
                root /var/www/eample.com/;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
                fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;
                fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
                fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9003;
        }
}
```

ps. all the fcgi stuff inside location / is web.py setup and has worked previously so i don't think thats the problem

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: ah, I should make that more obvious! my site isnt available from `test.ks12345.kimsufi.com` which is what I am trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

You have no DNS entry, this is not nginx related. Kimsufi only gave you the ks12345 subdomain and you need a DNS entry for test.ks12345 in order to reach your server. Check your hosting package if you can control your DNS. Ask Kimsufi, but I believe this is not included in your package (because I know Kimsufi).